# How to use ng-repeat with div tag, where div contain multiple different tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have few tabs, the number of tab i am reading from some other page of the application, for all these tabs i've to show a table where value will be populated from database. How to use ng-repeat to show table for each tab as columns are same only values will be different.

```
 Tab1     Tab2     Tab3
Dropdown1    Dropdown2    Dropdown3    Dropdown4
```

By dafault it should display table for Tab1, and onClick Tab2 or Tab3 , whatever values are selected in  Dropdown1,Dropdown2,Dropdown3 & Dropdown4 same table with different entries will be displayed, as the structure of table and dropdown is same , how to use ng-repeat to achieve same. [similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOOZa.png) 
when this page will load for first time it should display table for first tab and in dropdown1 it should fetch value from some different page using scope variable. 
I have done it without using ng-repeat, any help how to do it using ng-repeat?

Comment: can you post your code here?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use scope.tables in controller and use the below sample code in your html file.

```
 <div ng-repeat="chart in chartConfigs">
 <div ng-if="x== chartConfigs[6] || x== chartConfigs[7] || x== chartConfigs[12]  ">
         <highchart style="width:400px;height:300px;" id="chart" config="x">
         </highchart>
          </div>
          </div>
```

I used this code for displaying different high charts. You can use ng-repeat="table in tables"

Comment: Thank you, but I need to repeat same table, so table in tables is like how   :(? This ng-repeat is something similar to foreach loop if i am not wrong.